# can take picture with PI camera

Tags: camera

I have used the command  raspistill -o image.jpg to take a picture.

when the command is executed, the camera will show the red light, but the light on the camera won't stop until I stop the PI, I also looked at the picture taken from the camera. it showed  image.jpg~, when I opened it, nothing was in the image, 0 byte.

Why?

Comment: add the verbose option and post what is output, i.e. use the command `raspistill -v -o image.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this happen when there is a connection problem.
Double check that both ends of the ribbon are not damaged and inserted fully.

Second guess would be power supply problem. The camera can use quite a lot (relatively) amount of power

Answer (score 1):

Please note that raspistill has a **default timeout of 5**, which basically means the waiting time in seconds before taking a picture.

To make raspistill run fast execute the following:

```
raspistill -o shot.jpg --nopreview --exposure sports --timeout 1
```

Also check out my answer at [Raspistill slow to trigger?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23698/raspistill-slow-to-trigger/43194#43194) for how to take fast pictures.